# How to understand in other words the title of the text "Sailing into history"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Sailing into History
By Cesar G

Imagine yourself on a boat looking out at the horizon and all you can see is the water meeting the sky with no land in sight and you are sailing straight ahead to meet the world. Jesse Martin does not have to imagine: he is living it.

On Dec. 7, 1998, at 17 years old, Jesse departed from Melbourne, Australia  on his boat Lionheart to attempt to become the youngest person to sail solo and nonstop around the world. He sailed south of New Zealand, through the South Pacific, around South America, north on the Atlantic, back south past Africa, through the Indian Ocean and back to Melbourne.

Answer (score 2):

Martin went sailing, and (once his attempt was successful) he became part of a historical event: he became part of "history". Thus, he was "sailing into history".

Comment: If he had done it in a plane, it might have been "Flying into History", or a bicycle, "Pedalling into History". The verb denotes the method by which he undertook the journey which became part of history.

Answer (score 1):

The "Sailing" in the title is used in place of "Journey" or "Travel" to represent the path of the reader through the text.

By specifically selecting the word "Sailing" in the title, the author is trying to create parallels between your journey of imagination (as a reader picturing the events of the book) and the life of the character Jesse Martin who apparently spent a large amount of time sailing on one or more oceans.

Comment: I don't see this at all.